# Removing a class with delay()

Tags: jquery

I've looked at other examples but can't find one like this:

What I'm trying to do:
Have the '.Wrapper' element change background color when the element '.box1' is clicked, then after delay(x) have the .Wrapper revert to its prior state. (The background color is added from a class called '.clicked1')

The code I have right now adds '.clicked1', but I can't figure out how to remove the class via delay.

Any help?

```
$(function () {
$('.box1').click(function () {
    $('.Wrapper').addClass('clicked1')
});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with .delay()

```
$(function () {
    $('.box1').click(function () {
        $('.Wrapper').addClass('clicked1').stop().delay(2000).queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('clicked1')
        })
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8NFw/)

or using `setTimeout()`

```
$(function () {
    $('.box1').click(function () {
        $('.Wrapper').addClass('clicked1');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.Wrapper').removeClass('clicked1');
        }, 2000)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hFHka/)

Comment: You forgot the timeout in the `setTimeout` :)

Comment: Works, but not multiple times. In the situation I'm using this for 4 buttons similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/d8NFw/2/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `delay` but `setTimeout` :

```
$('.box1').click(function () {
    $('.Wrapper').addClass('clicked1')
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.Wrapper').removeClass('clicked1')
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Because it works on animation queue functions. If you use delay, you still have to add another function call to queue your function.

Comment: No more functions than setTimeout requires? or are you refering to the call for delay, and then the call for queue?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the use of queue and delay instead of just setTimeout. It doesn't work directly because not all jquery functions use the animation queue.

Answer (score 0):

First, store a reference to your timer and secondly, cache $(this)

```
(function() {
 var timer;
 $('.box1').click(function() {
   var el = $(this);

   el.addClass('clicked1');

   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(function() {
       el.removeClass('clicked1');
   });

 });
}());
```